# Mongoose setOnInsert : use computed property inside the query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I'm using setOnInsert in Mongoose console returns me that I can't use computed property inside setOnInsert as following message illustrate it:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

```
 findOneAndUpdate:{
     "filter": hour[daySlot].time.timePlot, 
     "$setOnInsert": { hour[daySlot][time]:  update }, // fails to use computed properties
     upsert: true
 }
```

My parameter are dynamics and I need to use computed properties.

Any hint would be great,
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use square brackets around `hour[daySlot][time]`

```
findOneAndUpdate:{
     "filter": hour[daySlot].time.timePlot, 
     "$setOnInsert": { [hour[daySlot][time]]:  update }, // fails to use computed properties
     upsert: true
 }
```

Comment: This is ES2015 syntax